# Задача с рекурсией из ЕГЭ

Tags: python, рекурсия

Определите наименьшее число *n* такое, что при вызове F(*n*) второе выведенное число будет больше числа 51. Запишите в ответе сначала найденное значение *n*, а затем через пробел - соответствующее значение F(*n*).

```
def F(n):
  print(n)
  if n > 0:
    d = (n%10 + F(n//10))
    print(d)
    return d
  else:
    return 0
```

P. S. Задача вроде и несложная, но возник конфликт с учителем по поводу ответа, поэтому задаю этот вопрос сюда.

Comment: Конфликт насчет чего?

Comment: ... ответ-то очевиден...

Comment: И что у вас получилось?

Comment: Ну очевидно, что второе выведенное число будет равно `n // 10`, если n > 0. Тогда наименьшее n это 520.